# How to read or control a pin from different thread in C# and Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I have a C# WebAPI application running on Raspberry Pi that controls a water valve.  I want to be able to open the valve for 60 minutes on one thread and check the state on a separate thread.  I have separate threads for opening the valve and checking the state which work correctly on their own.  The problem I'm having is the thread for checking the state doesn't read the correct value until the original open thread is finished.

How can I read or control a pin from a different thread?

Also, I'm using the System.Device.Gpio library.

This is the code I have.

```
...
using System.Device.Gpio;
...

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WaterValveSensorController : ControllerBase
{
    private GpioController controller = new GpioController();

    [HttpGet("{gpioPin}")]
    public WaterValveReading Get(int gpioPin)
    {
        //This method is intended for adhoc requests to get the status of the watervalve whether the valve is open or closed.

        var valveOpen = IsPinOpen(gpioPin);

        var waterValveReading = new WaterValveReading(microComputer.HostName, microComputer.IP, gpioPin, valveOpen, DateTimeOffset.Now);
        
        return waterValveReading;
    }

    [Route("[action]/{gpioPin}/{wateringSeconds}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task StartWatering(int gpioPin, int wateringSeconds)
    {
        var maxWateringSeconds = int.Parse(configuration["WaterValveSettings:MaxWateringSeconds"]);

        if (OpenValve(gpioPin))
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((wateringSeconds > maxWateringSeconds) ? maxWateringSeconds : wateringSeconds));
        }
    }

    private bool OpenValve(int gpioPin)
    {
        if (!IsPinOpen(gpioPin))
        {
            controller.OpenPin(gpioPin, PinMode.Output);
            controller.Write(gpioPin, PinValue.High);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool IsPinOpen(int gpioPin)
    {
        return controller.IsPinOpen(gpioPin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe someone who was more familiar with the RPi web API stuff would have an easier time understanding, but your question doesn't seem that clear to me. It would help if you would describe your problem using more specific terminology, and make it clear _exactly_ what sort of inputs are made (e.g. what web request), and what _exactly_ the output is. For example, _"doesn't read the correct value until the original open thread is finished"_ could be read to mean that a value is read, but it's incorrect, or it could be read to mean that no value is read at all until the other request finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Get` function mixes up a few things. `IsPinOpen` asks whether the pin has been opened for reading/writing. It does not indicate whether the valve is open or not. Therefore using it to construct the `WaterValveReading` structure is quite pointless. Additionally, you need to be aware that the `GpioController` class is not currently thread safe, so opening/closing pins from different threads is dangerous (reading/writing the pin value should be safe, though).

```cs
    [HttpGet("{gpioPin}")]
    public WaterValveReading Get(int gpioPin)
    {
        //This method is intended for adhoc requests to get the status of the watervalve whether the valve is open or closed.

        bool valvePinOpen = IsPinOpen(gpioPin);
        WaterValveReading waterValveReading;
        if (valvePinOpen)
        {
            var isValveOpen = controller.Read(gpioPin);
            waterValveReading = new WaterValveReading(microComputer.HostName, microComputer.IP, gpioPin, isValveOpen, DateTimeOffset.Now);
        }
        else
        {
            waterValveReading = new WaterValveReading(....); // Some error return (pin not open)
        }
        return waterValveReading;
    }
```

Additionally, I would reconsider whether you want the pin number to be in the web request. Typically, that will be fixed by hardware (the valve is attached to a very specific pin), so that having it in the API would allow the caller to open and write any pin, with possibly undesired side effects. If you know the pin number beforehand, you can open the corresponding pin already in the constructor.